# set_time_limit не задает лимит

Tags: php

А как задать именно реальный лимит исполнения? Вот я задал set_time_limit на 1 секунду, ввел рекурсию, а браузер чето пытался загрузить около минуты и после написал Maximum execution time of 1 second exceeded.

Зачем тогда нужна эта функция? Я хочу сделать, чтобы если за 1 секунду страница полностью не загрузилась - не грузи ее дальше. Это реально?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ограничения set_time_limit() действует на стороне сервера, оно не влияет на ожидание Web-сервером ответа от PHP и ожидания клиентом передачи информации по сети. В вашем случае, если важна реакция на стороне клиента, возможно лучше воспользоваться AJAX-запросом и ограничить время ожидания средствами JavaScript в браузере.